# Lepton flavor violating process on loop level $\mu \rightarrow e \gamma$ via Higgs, Divergent integral

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, higgs, beyond-the-standard-model

I am stuck with calculating the proces $\mu \rightarrow e \gamma$ as in this diagram:
[image]
I wrote down the matrix element like this:
$$
\mathcal{M}=\bar{u}(p-q)\left[\int \frac{d^4k}{(2\pi)^4}A\frac{(k+m_\tau)(k'+m_\tau)}{(k'^2-m^2_\tau)(k^2-m^2_\tau)[(p-k)^2-m^2_\tau)]}(e\gamma^\sigma\epsilon_\sigma)\frac{m\tau}{v}\right]u(p)
$$

I'm new to calculating loop diagrams so I have trouble with the k integral. I know I have to integrate about the momentum from $-\infty$ to $\infty$.

$$
I=\int \frac{d^4k}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{(k+m_\tau)(k'+m_\tau)}{(k'^2-m^2_\tau)(k^2-m^2_\tau)[(p-k)^2-m^2_\tau)]}
$$

With the denominator I have to go through all the standard stuff. Using Feynman parameters $x,y,z$, since I have three propagators. Then shifting the integration variable 
$$\ell=k-xq-zp$$ 
In the end I get
$$
2\int_0^1dx dy dz \frac{\delta(x+y+z-1)}{[\ell^2-\Delta+i\epsilon]^3}
$$
Now for $I$ there are 3 types of integrals the ones with no $k$ in the numerator with $k$ in the numerator and with $k^2$ in the numerator.
The one with no k is working fine so far. I can do a Wick rotation and then integrate in 4 dimensional spherical coordinates in Euklidean space. With a substitution I can simply calculate the integral here...
And when substituting $k$ by
$$
k=\ell+xq+zp
$$
I can drop all the terms linear in $\ell$ in the numerator since they cancel out due to symetric integration.
Am I correct so far?
The main question is: for the integral of the type:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty d^4\ell \frac{\ell^2}{[\ell^2-\Delta+i\epsilon]^3}
$$
If I do the Wick rotation here and with the spherical coordinates I get an extra $\ell³$. This integral becomes divergent for large $\ell$. As far as I know there should be no infinities here, as compared to the vacuum polarization in QED. Am I missing something? Or how can I calculate this integral?

Comment: Looks like it's just log divergent, have you tried using dim reg?

Comment: Your integral is schematically the same as the calculation of the electron vertex function in QED (anomalous magnetic moment and all that). This is standard and appears in any QFT textbook (for instance Peskin and Schroeder 6.2, 6.3, and the end of 7.2). The log divergence you are seeing is expected.

Comment: @InertialObserver thanks for your comments. So first I have to say I don't really know anything about regularization and that stuff. The proffesor who gave me that task said the calculation should be fine for me as the integrals are finite. So obviously they aren't.

Comment: @octonion the anomalous magnetic moment calculation is the only loop diagram I have ever calculated so far... so I will take a second look at it. But my professor told me there shouldn't be any infinities in this calculation. That's why I was confused. And also... Isn't the problem in QED arising because the photon is massless and one puts an extra term in the calculation with a massive photon to cancel the divergency? But here the Higgs boson is massive... But yes I understand that there is a log divergency... So would I just do the same as in the QED calculation here?

Comment: It looks like the powers of k all check out and so the naive divergence is log divergence.. the easiest thing to do would just to impose a momentum cutoff, which just means integrating to some scale $\Lambda$

Comment: I do know that the QED vertex correction to the Higgs is proportional to the cutoff, which gives rise to the famous vacuum instability problem which could be creeping in here

Comment: @higgshunter, Yes, as far as I can tell it is exactly the same as the QED calculation. Your final integral in terms of $l$ and $\Delta$ even appears in Peskin, (6.50)

Comment: @higgshunter, it amounts to flavor changing neutral current (FCNC) (felicitated by the right-most vertex $l_j \rightarrow l_i + H$). Is it suppressed?

Comment: @MadMax I'm very sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Could you explain more? But yes, the right-most vertex is the one that violates the flavor.

Comment: @higgshunter, google the GIM mechanism (or Glashow–Iliopoulos–Maiani mechanism) for the suppression of FCNCs.

Comment: But first, isn't the GIM mechanism only about charged weak currents, namely the W boson? A process that would be affected by that is a similar diagram to mine with a W boson and neutrino oscillation. But I am working with a neutral scalar. And my question wasn't about whether that process is suppressed or not but about calculating it no matter of suppression. This could happen i.e in an extended Higgs sector like the 2HDM where both doublets couple to all fermions.

Comment: @higgshunter, suppression of FCNC is an observational fact. Any beyond-Standard-Model would have to be in compliance with it. Case in point, Technicolor has to sweat over it.

Comment: @MadMax Yeah I get your point. I know that no such process has been measured. In my matrix element A is the coupling of the LFV vertex. The smallness or even a value of 0 would then make my calculation compatible with the SM. And actually for me it was not about the theoretical framework in which such a process could happen but more about the way of calculating it. But I know one has to consider that. I posted answer below that helped me understand why there are no term of $\ell^2$. But if you follow the link I posted, I still have trouble fully reproducing it. So maybe you :) Thanks:)

Comment: @higgshunter, $\int_{-\infty}^\infty d^4\ell \frac{\ell^2}{[\ell^2-\Delta+i\epsilon]^3} = \int_{-\infty}^\infty d^4\ell \frac{\ell^2-\Delta + \Delta}{[\ell^2-\Delta+i\epsilon]^3} = \int_{-\infty}^\infty d^4\ell \frac{1}{[\ell^2-\Delta+i\epsilon]^2} +  \int_{-\infty}^\infty d^4\ell \frac{\Delta}{[\ell^2-\Delta+i\epsilon]^3}$. The first logarithmic divergent and the second converging integrals can be readily obtained (consult any good QFT book).

Comment: @MadMax please read my answer below. It states that the divergent integral doesn't even appear in the final calculation... You can find an example of that in Cheng&Li "Gauge theory of elementary particle physics" in section 13.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found out that the Integral might be divergent but this divergency will cancel out later in the calculation, so it's not important to calculate. Actually one should not just start computing this diagram straight away but first find out the form of the amplitude.

A good reference for this is Cheng and Li "Gauge theory of elementary particle physics". In section 13.3 they calculate a similar diagram but with neutrino oscillation. The further calculation might be different but the derivation of the form of the amplitude is the same. Thus one finds out that all terms proportional to $\ell^2$ in the numerator cancel.

If one wants to know more about it he can also take a look here:

[Lorentz decomposition of electromagnetic current Cheng&Li $\mu\rightarrow e\gamma$ p.421](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/472235/226020)

where I explained the steps. I just need help to reproduce them. But this question should be answered by this...